# A select element that is not visible

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I use bootstrap and try to display a select box. But the select box is not visible.

HTML:

```
<div class="textAlignCenter">   
        <select  class="selectpicker" placeholder="Situation maritale" formControlName="maritalSituation">
          <option value="" selected></option>
            <option value="MARIE">Marié</option>
            <option value="DIVORCE">Divorcé</option>
            <option value="CELIBATAIRE">Célibataire</option>
            <option value="VEUF">Veuf</option>
        </select>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.textAlignCenter {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/flamant/awrb4Lxz/3/

Comment: What exactly is not visible? I can see the element just fine in the fiddle.

Comment: Seems to show..please explain your issue clearly

Comment: I think I have a problem with my computer or my browser.That is the second time that I have an unexplicable problem with css

Answer (score 0):

Select elements don't work like that. To display a "placeholder", you can replace your first `<option>` by something like this:

```
<option value="" selected disabled>Situation maritale</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was my browser that didn't work. I upgraded firefox with the latest version and restart and it worked. Could you please remove the negative mark please ? Thank you. The post is closed

Comment: Its better to delete the question, as it probably wouldn't help future readers